# Adjust gap between 2 columns to make them look straight

Tags: sed, awk, solaris, line-editor, text-formatting

`file1.txt`:

```
hi
wonderful
amazing
sorry
superman
superhumanwith
loss
```

`file2.txt` :

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

When i try to combine using paste -d" " file1.txt file2.txt > actualout.txt

`actualout.txt` :

```
hi 1
wonderful 2
amazing 3
sorry 4
superman 5
superhumanwith 6
loss 7
```

But i want my output to look like this
desired

`OUT.txt` :

```
hi             1
wonderful      2
amazing        3 
sorry          4
superman       5 
superhumanwith 6
loss           7
```

Which command can be used to combine 2 files an look like the desired output?
Solaris 5.10
ksh
nawk, sed, paste

Comment: You need to find the length of the longest word in file1; I would turn to perl for this one. Do you require  a nawk/sed/paste-only solution?

Comment: What's lenght maximum  of your file1?

Comment: i dont want to use perl, yes i want awk only solution. Could you provide mea a command to find the longest word in file 1 using awk or sed and then use it to get the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR==1{f+=1;w++;}
     f==1{if(length>w) w=length; next;}
     f==2{printf("%-"w"s",$0); getline<f2; print;}
    ' f2=file2 file1 file1
```

Note: `file1` is quite intentionally read twice; the first time is to find the maximum line length, and the second time is to format each line for the final concatenation with corresponding lines from file2. — `file2` is read programatically; its name is provided by awk's *variable-as-an-arg* feature.

Output:

```
hi             1
wonderful      2
amazing        3
sorry          4
superman       5
superhumanwith 6
loss           7
```

---

To handle any number of input files, the following works.but *Note: it does not cope with repeating the same filename. ie each filename arg refers to a different file. It can, however, handle files of different lengths - beyond a files EOF, spaces are used.

```
awk 'BEGIN{ for(i=1; i<ARGC; i++) { 
              while( (getline<ARGV[i])>0) { 
                 nl[i]++; if(length>w[i]) w[i]=length; }
              w[i]++; close(ARGV[i])
              if(nl[i]>nr) nr=nl[i]; }
            for(r=1; r<=nr; r++) {
              for(f=1; f<ARGC; f++) {
                if(r<=nl[f]) getline<ARGV[f]; else $0=""  
                printf("%-"w[f]"s",$0); } 
              print "" } }
    ' file1 file2 file3 file4
```

Here is the output with 4 input files:

```
hi             1 cat   A 
wonderful      2 hat   B 
amazing        3 mat   C 
sorry          4 moose D 
superman       5       E 
superhumanwith 6       F 
loss           7       G 
                       H
```

Comment: It worked albeit with nawk instead of awk as my box is solaris

Comment: now how to combine multiple files like this, lets say i have 4 files? just repeat this process 3 times?

Comment: You've gotta read it twice - at least. It's why I tried `grep` -  most `grep`'s will `-q`uit at the first match in `-q` mode and it was the sanest simple solution I could think of. But this is all-in-one - and exactly what was asked for to boot, as opposed to some hodge-podge. I like it.

Comment: Yes, I thought reading a file *twice* would irk quite a lot of people :) - I could have used an array, but this way has no potential to  run out of memory, and I just liked the simplicity of no programmed loops.

Comment: With an array you would not only have to read it twice, but also copy it. Most modern systems will minimize the differences via disk cache anyway. I never liked arrays and usually prefer `tmpfs`  for stuff like this. I can't tell the difference performance wise, and it's easier to use - writing/reading files is what I know.

Comment: @ayrton_senna: I have added an `awk`-only *multiple files* version.

Comment: @Peter.O Thanks your multi file solution worked with **nawk** (as my box is SOLARIS 5.10). Now i dont have to worry about finding which column will have longest word.

Comment: @ayrton_senna: Please note that I have just now **modified the code** (for both code samples) to fix a bug in column spacing calculation. - see `w++` and `w[i]++` - I also added `next` to 1st version (not essential, but saves a bit of processing time by avoiding condition test `f==2`)

Answer (score 8):

You seem to need `column`:

```
paste file1.txt file2.txt | column -tc2
```

which creates this output:

```
hi              1
wonderful       2
amazing         3
sorry           4
superman        5
superhumanwith  6
loss            7
```

You can of course also write your own script to do the formatting. Here is one way using `awk`:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR { a[FNR] = $0 ; if (length > max) max = length ; next }
  { printf "%-*s  %s\n", max, a[FNR], $0 }
' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: Not available by default on Solaris.

Comment: @lcd047; Not "per default" - so it can be made available? - If not then there's the fallback to old `pr`, as in: `pr -tm file1.txt file2.txt`

Comment: @Janis No man entry for column in solaris 5.10. I tagged it for solaris, any alternate solution?

Comment: @Janis pr -tm seems to having limitations when the length of sting in first column is greater than 24 characters, can we adjust this? so that it prints all charaters in each column?

Comment: You can adjust the page width with `pr`'s option `-w` to a larger value. But that would be quasi ad hoc and hard coded. - If you want it be determined dynamically, and if you haven't tools like `columns` available, then as a last resort you would have to implement the function yourself. - I'll add yet another program in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

#### `pr`

I'd probably go w/ `pr`:

```
printf %s\\n hi wonderful amazing sorry  \
             superman superhumanwith loss >/tmp/file
#^what is all of that, anyway?^

seq 7 | pr -tm /tmp/file -
```

`pr` can `-m`erge input files *(here `/tmp/file` and `-` stdin)* line-by-line like `paste` column-wise, but it can take *many* other parameters besides. By default it will print headers and footers as well, but `-t` squashes that.

#### OUTPUT:

```
hi                      1
wonderful               2
amazing                 3
sorry                   4
superman                5
superhumanwith          6
loss                    7
```

#### `expand`

If you're interested in getting more specific on your own, another option is `expand` - because you can hand it a list of virtual tab-stops which it will *expand* to as many spaces as are necessary to fill them.

```
seq 7 | paste /tmp/file - | expand -t15
```

Here we only need the first `-t`abstop of course...

```
hi             1
wonderful      2
amazing        3
sorry          4
superman       5
superhumanwith 6
loss           7
```

...but if more were wanted...

```
seq 14 | paste /tmp/file - /tmp/file - | expand -t15,23,38,46
```

...we could spell them out in a compounding, comma-separated list...

```
hi             1       hi             2
wonderful      3       wonderful      4
amazing        5       amazing        6
sorry          7       sorry          8
superman       9       superman       10
superhumanwith 11      superhumanwith 12
loss           13      loss           14
```

#### `grep`:

To find the length of the longest line in a file, and not counting any trailing spaces, and as incremented by standard 8-char tabstop positions, this will probably work:

```
i=0
while grep -Eq ".{$(((i+=8)-1))}.*[^[:blank:]]" <infile; do :; done
```

That loop will increment `$i` by 8 for each run and search *`<infile`* for any line which contains at least as many characters as are counted in `$i` followed by any not blank character. And so when `grep` cannot find such a line, it will return false and, for your example data, it will assign:

```
echo "$i"
16
```

#### `wc`:

But those are all POSIX solutions. The most simple thing to do on a GNU system is:

```
wc -L <infile
```

...to list out the length of the longest line in *`<infile`*, but that will include counts for trailing blanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on doing it with `awk`:

```bash
awk -v file=file2.txt '{
        cnt++
        a[cnt] = $0
        getline b[cnt] <file
        if(length(a[cnt]) > max)
            max = length(a[cnt])
    }
    END {
        max++
        for(i = 1; i <= cnt; i++)
            printf "%-" max "s%s\n", a[i], b[i]
    }' file1.txt
```

On a side note: I'm pretty sure this particular wheel has been re-invented a zillion times already, but right now I'd rather not coerce my brain to come up with the right incantation to find proper examples of prior SE / SO art. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, i found myself what i wanted. This works in Solaris 5.10.

`paste file1 file2| pr -t -e$(awk 'n<length {n=length} END {print n+1}' file1)`

I am storing the length of longest string in first file and using it to tab delimit

**Multi File scenario**

Provided we know which file is going to have the longest word i would replace that file name in calculating length and use paste to join multiple files.
If file4.txt has the longest string.
Then solution would be

`paste file1 file2 file3 file4 | pr -t -e$(awk 'n<length {n=length} END {print n+1}' file4)`

Comment: Do you need quotes around `-e$(...)` or are you splitting that intentionally? You also should be able to do pretty similarly `pr -tm file[1234]`.

Comment: You don't need to know which file will have the longest line. Use your exact solution, just run it on all files: `paste file{1..4} | pr -t -e$(awk 'n<length {n=length} END {print n+1}' file{1..4})`

Comment: Will that work if the files have different names instead of file1, file2, file3 and file4. I guess not.